# CPU usage of named daemon on CentOS 6

Tags: cpu, centos, bind

I'm having an issue with the name server daemon using up more CPU than I can understand. I got to this issue while trying to figure out why the VPS I'm running feels slow.

First off, the problem of `named` having a high-CPU usage is not new: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059014/bind-named-service-high-cpu-load) provided me with steps meant to fix the issue. The problem I have is that although I've followed [the steps in the detailed answer by @efesaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568859) with success, I still see a quite active and CPU-hungry process.

The server is a VPS running an up-to-date CentOS 6.8 with basic server services and strictly nothing fancy (web server with PHP5.5 support, FTP, e-mail server, and LDAP). `yum list installed bind` reveals that the version of the installed package is 9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6.

I've just checked the contents of all zone files and, as far as I can tell, the contents is correct. There are only 4 zones and an average of 6 records per zone.

Here is a screenshot of `top` (although the display is not sorted by time, I can confirm that `named` is by far the greediest process – the values in the screenshot represent a rough average of 11.7% over the course of two days):

[image: Screenshot of system monitoring using top]

I've already started to prepare a migration to CentOS 7, and I've installed a VM on my computer for testing. But since this option would require much work, with making backups, reinstalling all software, migrating the data and duplicating/adapting the configuration, let alone testing, I'm left with considering other options.

Although just about every post or message I could find online points to adding `managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";` in the configuration file and stops there, I feel like there's something inherently wrong with a non-serving daemon that *never* goes idle. I've SSH'ed into my VPS 9 hours ago and it's the only process that has been *constantly* running.

Is there anything more I can do to figure out what's going on? To be clear, I know there's a problem with the named process and I'm trying to diagnose it.

Also, given that the issue is [supposed to have been dealt with](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=709205#c29) in version 9.9.3 and CentOS 6 is using 9.8.2, is using a non official repository that provides an updated version of bind?

Comment: Did you look at `bind`'s logs to see what the requests look like or if it produces errors?  Is your `bind` accepting recursive requests?  Do you have any type of security like `fail2ban` which could be used to block certain abuses?

Comment: Yes, I did. I checked, per indications on the other question I linked to, the logs in the data/named.run file. No errors whatsoever. There were warnings such as `NS has no address records (A or AAAA)` and I fixed them earlier today, which didn't change anything as to this problem. Is that the logs you are referring to?

Comment: And yes, the server accepts recursive requests. But it's eating up CPU even when reporting no active requests. fail2ban service is active and has 0 jails.

Comment: You should **never** have an open DNS server unless you wish to attract DNS attacks.  To troubleshoot, do a request on your DNS server and see if it appears in the log.

Comment: Following your comment, I have stopped the name server on my VPS and resorted to using the name servers offered by the ISP, which is OVH. I guess they'll do a better job at securing their name servers than I can at securing mine and that generally speaking they'll know better. I'll later see to disabling it entirely. Merci, Julie.